# ES6 Angularjs directive, passed in function from calling controller has no constructor variables

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ecmascript-6

*I am using ES6 but I am not sure this is an ES6 issue*

I am trying to implement a 'login with google' button using the google api  `gApi` and angular.  I have wrapped the gApi call into a directive.  The directive takes a string `clientId` and a function called `onSuccessFunction`.  The on success function gets called on a successful sign in.  Currently I am just trying to log the profile information on successful login, but I get an error when it tries to call the first this.log.debug (`this.log` is assigned in the constructor) function, complaining that `this` is undefined.

What can I do to fix this?

**Controller**

```
class LoginController {
  /*@ngInject*/
  constructor($scope, $log) {
    this.name = 'login';
    this.clientId = 'ourClientID';
    this.log = $log;
  }

  loggedIn(googleUser) {
    let profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    this.log.debug('ID: ' + profile.getId()); 
    this.log.debug('Name: ' + profile.getName());
    this.log.debug('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
    this.log.debug('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());
  }
}
```

**View**

```
<google-login-button client-id="loginCtrl.clientId" on-success-function="loginCtrl.loggedIn"></google-login-button>
```

**Directive**

```
class googleLoginButton {
  /*@ngInject*/
  constructor() {
    this.template = '<div></div>';
    this.scope = {
      clientId: '@',
      onSuccessFunction: '&'
    };
  }

  link(scope, element, attrs) {
    var div = element.find('div')[0];
    div.id = attrs.clientId;
    gapi.signin2.render(div.id, { 'onsuccess': scope.onSuccessFunction() }); //render a google button, first argument is an id, second options
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a method is being passed through binding, it loses its context. It is the same thing as doing

```
let onSuccessFunction = LoginCtrl.loggedIn;
onSuccessFunction(...);
```

It should be

```
  constructor($scope, $log) {
    ...
    this.loggedIn = this.loggedIn.bind(this);
  }
```

As a rule of thumb, every method that is supposed to be used as a callback, should be bound.

Comment: You are my hero.   Thank you.

Is this an ES6 thing or a directive thing?

Comment: It is JS thing, to be precise. It would be the same problem for any JS object if it would have a method that refers to `this`.